# How to show Toast Counting down before transfer to another activity-Android Studio

Tags: java, android

i have made this code

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EnterData.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, 7000);
```

how i can show the count down by toast? for example i made this counting 7 seconds before go to another page i need toast dialog show counting 7.6.5.4,etc then transfer

Thanks

Comment: simply use countdown timer

Comment: do you want a single toast to show the countdown or multiple toasts with a number in each?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a CountDownTimer

```
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(7000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EnterData.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    };
```

Somewhere you feel its appropriate you can start the count like this:

```
countDownTimer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a second handler which will do the count down for you.

For this create a static variable countdown as follows in MainActivity.java

```
private static int countdown = 7;
```

This can be used in the new handler to show the toast for countdown.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(context,MainActivity.countdown+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    MainActivity.countdown--;
    }
}, 1000);
```

Also keep your handler, which will create the intent and start it after 7 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

you can create timerClass as bellow

```
class SayCount extends TimerTask {
public void run() {
 if(i == 0 ) {
   timer.stop();
  }
   System.out.println(String.valueOF(i)); 
   i--;
}
}


// And From your main() method or any other method
int i = 7;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new SayCount(), 0, 1000);
```

or you can use Runnable() class as the answer above